# Highlight color for favorite-tagged questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, bookmarks

As you all know questions that have one of the user's favorite tags are highlighted (in all of the StackExchange sites), but the highlight color in this site is not easily recognized, it's not comfort for the eyes.

I think it's better to make it stronger and more distinguished, perhaps a darker blue.

A problem might appear is that when darkening that color, it might become difficult to read the question title because it's already a darker blue, so maybe we'll need to further darken the color of the question title and the name of the recent user active in it (the name that appears in the bottom-right corner).

This is only a proposal, subject to agreement and discussion, so what do you say?

Comment: I would actually like to see only the questions I've tag as being interested om, but not sure if that's possible?

Comment: This is precisely the thing I just wanted to post here. It bothers me as well.